# Guest Internet access for an hotel

Tags: centos, ldap, access-point, dhcp-server

First of all, thanks so much for all the help from all the techies on this site.

We have to implement  the ability for guests to use the internet over wireless for an hotel.

When guests check into the hotel, if they scan for wireless networks they should get connected to the wireless access point without a password. Once they open any web page, they should be redirected to the hotel main page to enter an access password.

Guests should have a username/password screen where username=cellphone number and password=room number of the guest.

The above implementation is to be done using open source products as the hotel don't want to spend money on software.

What we have in testing at the moment in our lab is as follows:

|ISP|-->|Router|-->|Switch|-->|CentOS - with 2 NIC |-->|Access Point|-->|Guest Laptop/IPAD/Phone|

What will we need to install and configure in order to achieve this? Do you have any guidelines?

Thanks Neolix and Team.

Comment: pfsense has an Captive portal with vauchers support or user login

Comment: @neolix there is a software named zeroshell its free. You coult test it. Its a complete Router Software with Captive Portal.

Comment: We are install the same on the on old PC thanks you so much for you help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want something called a Captive Portal - bear in mind doing this with *no* software budget is not quite right/easy. A wireless network in a hotel will not (should not) be a couple of consumer access points scattered around the hotel.

You're slighty unclear of what you have - do you want the captive portal to run on the CentOS box or something else?

If something else you could set up a device (hardware cost) running the DD-WRT firmware (free) which has a captive portal that the access points feed into, but this reeks of cheapness - I'd really reccomend using a proper wireless solution, and if you are that should offer a Captive Portal option.

Comment: Hi Tombull89 Sorry for uncleanness in my writing "Captive Portal" is right solution we also feel. thanks a ton :)